# Chart with Multiple CandleStick. HighStock/HighCharts

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, candlestick-chart

I want to do a chart with multiple candlestick series. Im getting the series drawn one on the top of other and i want them grouped next to each other.

Is it possible to achive this:

http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-basic

with candleStick series?

If you have in mind some other aprroach that can help me, please feel free to share it.

Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately candlestick cannot be grouped as you achieved.